# What are the major differences between different reagents used for hydrolysis?

Tags: organic-chemistry

While doing questions on hydrolysis, i often get confused about what will happen if different reagents are used in hydrolysis... Such as H+ ; H+/H2O ; H+/H2O/heat ; etc.
What exactly can we concur when these different reagents are given?

Comment: As a noobie to ChemSE you are expected to show your thoughts lest your post be closed.

Comment: Usually, H+ and H+/H2O mean the same thing

Comment: Those are the same reagents ( so does H+ and H3O+ ), but expressed differently. Heat is just different condition, speeding up reactions.